# I am trying to subtract 1 dataframe from another but I am getting random output

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes with 53 rows and 442 columns each and dtypes int64 for both. When I try to subtract one dataframe from another the number of columns in the resulting dataframes goes up significantly

df1.info() shows

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

RangeIndex: 53 entries, 0 to 52

Columns: 442 entries, A to ZZZ

dtypes: int64(442)

memory usage: 100 KB

df2.info() shows

RangeIndex: 53 entries, 0 to 52

Columns: 442 entries, A to ZZZ

dtypes: int64(442)

memory usage: 100 KB
```

but when I write

```
df3 = df1.subtract(df2, axis = 1) 

df3.info()
```

I get

```
RangeIndex: 53 entries, 0 to 52

Columns: **61924** entries, A to ZZZZZZZZZZ

dtypes: int64(61924)

memory usage: **25.0 MB**
```

Any ideas on what could be wrong? I have reset the index in both df1 and df2 before subtracting.

Comment: Your dataframes do not have exact same `columns`. Maybe `df1.sub(df2.values)`.

Comment: Check if `set(df1.columns) - set(df2.columns)` return empty? If yes, substract would work else use values to substract.

Comment: Thank you both. Solved with df1.sub(df2.values)